# Livewire Showing Blank Page upon Saving Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am trying to make a CRUD application using livewire to render data in the component Blade and save data to the DB there afterwards. The data is being render correctly to the livewire Blade component but when I try to save the data from the component, Livewire is rendering the blank page instead of updating the added data. Here is my code.

`Employees.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Livewire\Component;
use Session;
class Employees extends Component
{
    public $name, $email, $edit=false;
    

public function resetInputFields(){
    $this->name="";
    $this->email="";
}


public function create(){
    $this->create=true;
   
}



    public function store(){
        $this->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
         ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
           ]);
          Session::flash('success', 'Employee added successfully');
          $this->resetInputFields(); 
          
    }



    public function render()
    {
      $employees = User::latest()->paginate(5);
      return view('livewire.employees',compact('employees'));
    }



    
}
```

And here is my `employees.blade.php` blade component File

```
<x-app-layout>
<div>
<center>
   
   <h3 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px">Employees List </h3>
  
         <br>      


<!--Successs for Employee Addition-->
@if (Session::has('success'))
     <div class="alert alert-success w-75">
     {{ Session::get('success') }}
     </div>
@endif

<!-- Validation Errors -->
<x-auth-validation-errors class="mb-4" :errors="$errors" />

</center>
@include('livewire.create')

<br><br>
 
<div class="container shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">

<hr>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">NAME</th>
      <th scope="col">EMAIL</th>
      <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
           </tr>
  </thead>
  

  <tbody>
    @foreach($employees as $employee)
  <tr>

  <td>{{$employee->name}}</td>
   <td>{{$employee->email}}</td>
   <td>
     <span class="btn btn-success">Edit</span>
     <span class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span>
  </td>



    </tr>
    @endforeach
  
  </tbody>
  </table>
  {{ $employees->links() }}
  
</div>
</div>
</x-app-layout>
```

The `create.blade.php` is the modal being included in `employees.blade.php` and it appears as.

```
 <center>
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <button style="align-items:center"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Add Employees
      </button>
</center>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">        
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employees</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
 <!--Employee Name-->
 <label for="Name">Employee Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" wire:model.defer="name">
  <br>
        <!--Employee Email Address-->

        <label for="Email">Employee Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Employee Email" wire:model.defer="email">
      
      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" wire:click.prevent="store()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I save data in `employees.blade.php` the component is only showing a flash message of success without showing the updated data. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that I had two root elements. One in my `app.blade.php`

```
<div>
 
{{ $slot }} 

</div>
```

and another root element in my `employee.blade.php` as

```
<div>

My entire code here

</div>
```

So after removing one root element in my `app.blade.php` the template was rendered successfully.

Answer (score 0):

do you not need to redirect after the store / flash method

```
return redirect()->to('/render');
```

Comment: Thanks but again its redirecting to the render page which doesn't exist and giving a 404 error. Again in that case it will reload and I don't want it to reload as I am using livewire for SPA